# Build failed in KMM project in IOS Emulator due to Xcode Run Script phase without specified outputs

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm working on a Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile project, and while trying to build the iOS side, I'm encountering a build failure related to a script build phase. Here's the warning I'm receiving:

```
warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp')
```

This is followed by a build failure message:

```
The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/moataz/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Script-7555FFB5242A651A00829871.sh (in target 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp') (1 failure)
```

I am unsure how to address this warning and subsequent error within the environment. Has anyone faced a similar issue when building the iOS part of KMM projects in Android Studio? Any suggestions on how to address this or further diagnose the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The weird thing is that when I build the iOS App from JetBrains template it works without any problem, but when I create a new project in the Android studio and build the application, this error happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update kotlin version in build.gradle.kts file of the parent module like this:

```
plugins {
    //trick: for the same plugin versions in all sub-modules
    id("com.android.application").version("8.1.0").apply(false)
    id("com.android.library").version("8.1.0").apply(false)
    kotlin("android").version("1.9.10").apply(false)
    kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.9.10").apply(false)
   }
```

With this change, please also update the kotlin compiler extension version inside build.gralde.kts file of androidApp like this:

```
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.3"
    }
```

Refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin) for the compatibility version.
This change will fix the build issue on Xcode15.

I have created this [PR](https://github.com/Kotlin/kmm-production-sample/pull/74) for fixing the build issue in [KMM Production Sample](https://github.com/Kotlin/kmm-production-sample/pull/74) repo.

Comment: Tested and it worked perfectly. Thanks, Rizwan.

Comment: You're very welcome, @Moataz! I'm glad to hear that everything worked out perfectly for you.

Comment: That saved my day, I struggled for a full day to make the build work after xcode 15 update. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your build.gradle.kts file in "shared module":

```
if (System.getenv("XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR") == "1500") { 
    linkerOpts += "-ld64"
}
```

Like this:

```
listOf(
    iosX64(),
    iosArm64(),
    iosSimulatorArm64()
).forEach {
    it.binaries.framework {
        baseName = "shared"
        if (System.getenv("XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR") == "1500") {
            linkerOpts += "-ld64"
        }
    }
}
```

inside the forEach loop. This is a temporary fix, it is supposed to be fixed in Kotlin 1.9.10, but I don't get that as a choice so in the meantime,this fix makes the iOS version buildable!

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-60230#focus=Comments-27-7921542.0-0

Edit: Kotlin, not Gradle 1.9.10!

Comment: Oh man, you saved a lot of time. Hope we see this update soon. Thank you :)

Comment: Still facing this with Kotlin 1.9.21 , latest KMM plugin , Xcode 15 , any resole for this?

Answer (score 3):

I got this error and some others. But the problem was due to old version of **JDK** I had on Android studio. So I opened

**Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle**

in Android studio and in **Gradle JDK** drop down list I downloaded **openjdk-21** and the problem resolved.